# Div in between two divs

Tags: html, css

It's kind of hard to explain, so to make it easier I made this sketch:

[image]

I basically have two divs one outer div and one div inside that div. What i want to do is, I kind of want to add a line between the 2 divs. Is this possible and how should i approach this?

Comment: What is your code so far? Are you not wanting to just use `border-bottom` on the inner `div`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```css
#outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#inner {
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}
#line {
  position: absolute;
  width:1px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -25px; /*half the height*/
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The outer div is nothing special.

The inner div gets a relative position and the line div a absolute position.

By making the line div as child and the positions as mentioned above, the position gets defined relative to it's parent. So when using `left: 50%` that means, on 50% of the parent.

## Andrews alternativ

```css
#outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#inner {
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}
#inner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width:1px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -25px; /*half the height*/
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could remove that `#line` `div` and use `#inner:after` also. Takes away unneeded HTML. Just as an additional option

Comment: @Andrew, jup, added it as an alternativ :)

Comment: Exactly, thought no one would understand what I was talking about, since the question wasn't very clear, but yeah this is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it!